# In GCM, what is the error id in onError (Context context, String errorId)

Tags: android, error-handling, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In the GCM example for Android, the example GCMIntentService suggests Overriding the following method:

> onError(Context context, String errorId): Called when the device tries
>   to register or unregister, but GCM returned an error. Typically, there
>   is nothing to be done other than evaluating the error (returned by
>   errorId) and trying to fix the problem.

My question is, where does this error id come from? How do I determine if the error occurred on registration vs unregistering for example?

The [GCMBaseIntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#onError%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29) wasn't of much help either, specifying `errorId - error id returned by the GCM service.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the error codes specified by Google :

> If the application request (be it register or unregister) fails, the
>   error will be set with an error code, and the other extras will not be
>   set. Here are the possible error codes:
>
> **SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE**
>
> The device can't read the response, or there was a 500/503 from the
>   server that can be retried later. The Android application should use
>   exponential back-off and retry. See Advanced Topics for more
>   information.
>
> **ACCOUNT_MISSING**
>
> There is no Google account on the phone. The Android application
>   should ask the user to open the account manager and add a Google
>   account. Fix on the device side.
>
> **AUTHENTICATION_FAILED**
>
> Bad Google Account password. The Android application should ask the
>   user to enter his/her Google Account password, and let the user retry
>   manually later. Fix on the device side.
>
> **INVALID_SENDER**
>
> The sender account is not recognized. This must be fixed on the
>   Android application side. The developer must fix the application to
>   provide the right sender extra in the
>   com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER intent.
>
> **PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR**
>
> Incorrect phone registration with Google. This phone doesn't currently
>   support GCM.
>
> **INVALID_PARAMETERS**
>
> The request sent by the phone does not contain the expected
>   parameters. This phone doesn't currently support GCM.

(quote taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#registering))

Comment: In addition, if you extend GCMBaseIntentService the first error (SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE) is handled by that class. Source code here:[http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.java](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.java)

Comment: Missed that when going back and reviewing. Thanks!